# Storing button inside of php variable

Tags: php

I have following code:

```
$boxId = 1;
$explainationBox='<input type="button" id="<?php echo $boxId; ?>" value="send" onmousedown="javascript:callthis(<?php echo $buttonId; ?>);" class="button" />';
                  echo $explainationBox;
```

I am trying to save these values as html button inside of php variable explainationBox. But its not saving actual value of $boxId. It is just saving it as $boxId. As boxId is inside a for loop and will keep on changing. How can i do this?

Comment: another option: heredoc syntax http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not nedd `<?php` tag when this tag is already opened

Try this

```
$boxId = 1;
$explainationBox='<input type="button" id="'.$boxId.'" value="send"
           onmousedown="javascript:callthis('.$buttonId.');" class="button" />';
echo $explainationBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP tags in a string are not parsed (unless given to some functions such as `eval()`).

Use string concatenation.

Change this...

```
"<?php echo $boxId; ?>"
```

...to...

```
"' . $boxId . '"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it useful to enter and exit the php environment within the loop so you don't have so save that string as a variable at all.

```
for($i=1; $i<10; $i++){?>
     <input type="button" id="ID<?=$i?>" value="send"
       onmousedown="javascript:callthis('<?=$i?>');" class="button" />
<?php } ?>
```

So what we are doing is leaving the php environment as we open the loop (`?>`) then we give some raw html that will be plopped into the page as shown,  no variable needed.  Then while we are outside the php environment we use the `<?= $variable ?>` syntax to drop a php variable into the html language.  And finally we re-enter the php environment by reopenning the php tags (`<?php`).

Note: That last ?> would go wherever you wanted to re-exit php again.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working: 
$boxId = 1;
$explainationBox='';
echo $explainationBox;

except for: "javascript:callthis('.$buttonId.');" call. In order to make this whole code work here is a solution for those who are looking:

$boxId = 1;
$explainationBox='';
echo $explainationBox;